# Angular 6 - Remove node_module package and use it in for local project changes

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular6, ng2-smart-table

We have decided to go with ng2-smart-table for table grid in our project. But it is not supporting completely what we need to do in our project.

So we have decided to change code on its package level (Files inside to the node_modules directory). So I am not sure how to do it, because if I change something on their package level and if we run `npm install` command by mistakenly, it will overwrite our changes if they have any updates.

So what do we need to do if I want to made changes in the ng2-smart-table node_modules files. Simply removing entry from the `package.json` for `ng2-smart-table` will be good? Or is there any better way to do that?

Comment: node_modules is meant to be a library directory, and you shouldn't be editing libraries. You could fork ng2-smart-table and include your fork in the project on github and add it to npm and include that in your project. Or you could find a way to copy the source code into your project and never be able to get any feature/bug updates by the ng2-smart-table team. Or even ask for feature requests in the github. But you shouldn't be editing anything in your node_modules directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got 2 choices, I expect you will like the first:

(1) use npm patch-package ... https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package

You generate a patch for the package in the form of a diff. The patch is saved in your repo. When you npm install, it downloads the normal package and then patches it every time with the diff during a postinstall - postinstall fires automatically AFTER the npm install is complete.

(2) npm install the module you want to change, cd to the directory within node_modules - make the changes including changing the name in package.json then npm publish (all must be done within relevant dir within node_modules) - you have just published your own version of their package. Use that now instead.

In approach (1) I'm not sure how patch package would deal with updates to the original package. In approach (2) you will never get any more updates to the main package since this is now a totally new package which you have published to npm.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.